# How to color different cells based on the value of the cells in a Python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with different string values to be filled by different colors.
For the following DataFrame `df`, all I want is that different cells are in different colors. For example, the cells that have 'A' value is in red, the cells that have 'B' value is in green, and 'C' in blue, 'D' in grey, etc.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','B','D'],'b':['E','B','C'],'c':['F','A','D']})
```

How can I achieve this using the `Styler.apply`? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**Styling**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) with a dictionary of colors you want to map values to:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': ['A', 'B', 'D'], 'b': ['E', 'B', 'C'], 'c': ['F', 'A', 'D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image: ex2]

```
color_mapping = {'A': 'red', 'B': 'green', 'C': 'blue', 'D': 'gray', 'E': 'indigo', 'F': 'violet'}
df.style.applymap(lambda v: f"color: {color_mapping.get(v, 'black')}")
```

[image: ex3]

If you want the cells to be filled in with the color use `background-color` rather than `color`:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda v: f"background-color: {color_mapping.get(v, 'black')}")
```

[image: ex4]

In case you want to set background color and the text color to white for better readability:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda v: f"background-color: {color_mapping.get(v, 'black')}").applymap(lambda _: "color: white")
```

[image: ex5]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
col_dict = {'A': 'red', 'B': 'green', 'C': 'blue', 'D': 'gray'}
def colour_cell(val):
    if val in col_dict:
        return 'Background-color: %s' % col_dict[val]
    return ''
```

---

```
df.style.applymap(colour_cell)
```

One liner solution(assuming if all the values will have color assigned to it):

```
df.style.applymap(lambda v: 'Background-color: %s' % col_dict[v])
```

[image]